# Counter example to the continuity of measure with respect to decreasing sequence of sets and the first set having infinite measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let, $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),m ) $ be a measure space where $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers, $m$ is the counting measure, and $\mathcal{P}$ is the power set operator. Let, $A_0 = \mathbb{N}$ and  $A_{n} = \mathbb{N} - \{1,2,\dots,n \}$ where $n \ge 1$. Then, $(A_{n})_{n \ge 0}$ describes a sequence of decreasing sets. Observe that
$m(A_1) = m(\mathbb{N}) = \infty $ by definition of counting measure. We have that,
$$m(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n ) = m (\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n )  = m(\emptyset) = 0.$$
However,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(A_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\infty) = \infty.$$
Thus, the  measure $m$ does not commute with the limit operation because $m(A_1) = \infty$.

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your reasooning is correct but let's not say "measure does not commute with limit operation" because well taking limit is not an operation.(as far as i know) Let's say it is not sequentially continuos.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It does, however, commute if the sets $A_n$'s are of finite measure.